# Render the value of keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a data in csv format:

```
    Year,Relations,Female,Male
    2002,Family/Relative,0,0
    2002,Friend,0,0
    2002,Intimate Partner,0,0
    2002,Other,0,0
    2002,Unknown,1116,0
    2003,Family/Relative,0,0
    2003,Friend,0,0
    2003,Intimate Partner,0,0
    2003,Other,0,0
    2003,Unknown,364,15
    2004,Family/Relative,0,0
    2004,Friend,0,0
    2004,Intimate Partner,0,0
    2004,Other,0,0
    2004,Unknown,250,0
    2005,Family/Relative,0,0
    2005,Friend,0,0
    2005,Intimate Partner,0,0
    2005,Other,0,0
    2005,Unknown,1189,428
    2006,Family/Relative,0,0
    2006,Friend,0,0
    2006,Intimate Partner,0,0
    2006,Other,0,0
    2006,Unknown,1237,297
```

I want to render the population/value of each gender for each relationship in my stacked bar char, below is the code for reading the data:

```
d3.csv("realdata.csv").then(d => chart(d))

    function chart(csv) { 
        var keys = csv.columns.slice(2);

        var Year = [...new Set(csv.map(d => d.Year))]
        var Relations = [...new Set(csv.map(d => d.Relations))]

        var options = d3.select("#year").selectAll("option")
            .data(Year)
            .enter()
            .append("option")
            .text(d => d)
```

And below is the code for adding the tooltip:

```
var tip = d3.select(".d3-tooltip")
              .style("visibility", "hidden");

           svg.selectAll(".x-axis").transition().duration(speed)
              .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSizeOuter(0))

           var group = svg.selectAll("g.layer")
               .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data), d => d.key)

           group.exit().remove()

           group.enter().append("g")
             .classed("layer", true)
             .attr("fill", d => z(d.key))
             .on("mouseover", function(d) {
              tip.html("<p>" + d.key + "</p>")
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px")
                .style("visibility", "visible")
             })
             .on("mouseout", function(d) {
              tip.style("visibility", "hidden")
             });
```

In the code `tip.html("<p>" + d.key + "</p>"),` it only return Male or Female in the graph which is the key, however, I want to return the population/values.Below is the graph I have now:

[image]

How can I return the population/value of each gender corresponding to each relationship on this stacked bar chart?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the value as below.

```
tip.html("<p>" + d.key + " : " + d.value + "</p>")
```

Comment: I don't think this will works since I cannot access to the data using d.value